# The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am getting this error after using location package even though my kotlin gradle is fully updated.

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

Here is the snapshot of my gradle.build file [Gradle.build file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnsX0.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try opening your build.gradle files in Android Studio. The tooling for pointing out errors and fixes are much better there. Perhaps it'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: Getting same errors, not pointing out any solution for this issue